# How often does data.stackexchange update its data?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I just ran the query here: http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/208/keystrokes-per-rep-point

It has me at under 9000 rep, even though I currently have over 10000 rep (and consequently also over 9000! rep).  How is this data calculated?  How often is it updated?

Comment: Heh, tzenes has 4 times as many keystrokes as anyone else.  He's certainly thorough in his answers...

Comment: I scrolled down and laughed that it was a whole order of magnitude higher.

Comment: It was just updated with the data for the 6th of June (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94718/data-dumpification).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [front page of Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), it will tell you when the latest update was. As of right now, that is **May 9th 2011**, so it's over a month old.

Updates occur every 1-2 months. There was speak that it was going to be fixed at a bimonthly period, but it's not exactly been keeping up with that rate quite yet, so there's no telling whether or not the next update will be sooner or at the two month mark.